# Probability of getting a total score of exactly $r$

Tags: probability-theory

A player throws a ordinary die with faces numbered $1 $ to $6$.Whenever he throws $ 1$, he gets a further throw.then the probability of obtaining a total score of$ r$ is (Consider cases when $r>6$ and $1<r \leq 6$)---

Let $r=n*k+f$ where $k$ is the number of times 1 is thrown and $ f$ lies between 2 and 6 for the last throw.
.the possibility for f is $1/5$.

So total probability is

$$(1/6)^n(1/5)$$

I am not able to eliminate $n$ and maybe this is not the correct approach.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with probability distribution functions?

Comment: Yes,just a beginner,I have learnt it during the previous week.

Comment: No, you are guaranteed a score of at least $2$.  For example, if the first roll is a $2$, that is your score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\leq 6$, clearly $P(1) = 0$ and
$$P(2) = \frac16\\
P(3) =  \frac16+\frac1{36} = \frac7{36}\\
\vdots\\
P(6) = \frac16+\frac1{36}+\frac{1}{216}+\frac{1}{1296}+\frac{1}{7776} 
$$
That is, for $2\leq n \leq 6$
$$
P(n) = \frac16 \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac1{6^k} = 
\frac15 \left( 1-\left(\frac16\right)^{n-1}\right)
$$

For $n>6$ the only routes to a score of $n$ are starting with between $n-6$ and $n-2$ ones, and then rolling the right number to land at $n$.  This gives 
$$
P(n) =\frac16 \left[  \left(\frac16\right)^{n-6}+\left(\frac16\right)^{n-5}+\left(\frac16\right)^{n-4}+\left(\frac16\right)^{n-3}+\left(\frac16\right)^{n-2} \right]= \frac{1555}{6^{n-1}}
$$

So the full distribution is
$$
P(n) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 0 & \mbox{if }  n<2 \\
\frac15 \left( 1-\left(\frac16\right)^{n-1}\right) & \mbox{if }  2\leq n \leq 6 \\ \frac{1555}{6^{n-1}} & \mbox{if }  n > 6 
\end{array} \right.
$$

** EDIT NOTE **
IN response to a correction by  O. Von Seckendorff, I fixed the exponent in the $n>6$ case, which had erroneously been $n+3$ instead of $n-1$.

Comment: @ Mark Fischler that was a wonderful answer.thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I transcript correctly, but the distribution doesn't seem to add up to $1$. Link to WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+2+to+6+of+1%2F5(1-1%2F6%5E(n-1))+%2B+sum+from+7+to+inf+of+1555%2F6%5E(n%2B3)

Comment: Okay, there was a problem with the computation for the second part of the distribution. This seems to be the correct form: $P(n) = \frac{1555}{6^{n-1}}$. It adds to $1$ now. @navinstudent Try not be so proud. It was correct except for this mistake. Wolfram: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+2+to+6+of+1%2F5(1-1%2F6%5E(n-1))+%2B+sum+from+7+to+inf+of+1555%2F6%5E(n-1)

Comment: Thanks, @ O. Von Seckendorff.  I just made a mistake of a factor of 1296.  I will fix the error.